# XSLT - Adding 2 or more values from different nodes

Tags: xslt

I am trying to sum up all Units `peci:Units` according to the External Payroll code i.e, `Addtl_TO_Unpaid`.

1. For a worker if there are 3 `Addtl_TO_Unpaid` it should come up in one row only.
2. They should sum up and show the final output as 3 for units in this case. for eg: if there were 4 nodes of `Addtl_TO_Unpaid` with unit value as 1,1,1 and 3 respectively then I want 6 in output.

Code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Summary>
         <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2018-01-20T23:15:13.284-08:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
        <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
    </peci:Summary>
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Employee_ID>412548</peci:Employee_ID>
            <peci:Name>Mr AARON FORTUNE</peci:Name>
        </peci:Worker_Summary>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
             <peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>Additional Time Off
                    Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code>Addtl_TO_Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                <peci:Time_Off_Type>Additional_Time_Off_Paid_type</peci:Time_Off_Type>
                <peci:Unit_of_Time>DAYS</peci:Unit_of_Time>
                <peci:Time_Off_Entry>
                    <peci:Units>1</peci:Units>
                </peci:Time_Off_Entry>
            </peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions>
             </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>Additional Time Off
                    Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code>Addtl_TO_Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                <peci:Time_Off_Type>Additional_Time_Off_Paid_type</peci:Time_Off_Type>
                <peci:Unit_of_Time>DAYS</peci:Unit_of_Time>
                <peci:Time_Off_Entry peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Units>1</peci:Units>
                </peci:Time_Off_Entry>
            </peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="2">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>Additional Time Off
                    Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code>Addtl_TO_Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                <peci:Time_Off_Type>Additional_Time_Off_Paid_type</peci:Time_Off_Type>
                <peci:Unit_of_Time>DAYS</peci:Unit_of_Time>
                <peci:Time_Off_Entry peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Units>1</peci:Units>
                </peci:Time_Off_Entry>
            </peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="3">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
           <peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>Additional Time Off
                    Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
                <peci:External_Payroll_Code>Addtl_TO_Unpaid</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
                <peci:Time_Off_Type>Additional_Time_Off_Paid_type</peci:Time_Off_Type>
                <peci:Unit_of_Time>DAYS</peci:Unit_of_Time>
                <peci:Time_Off_Entry peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Units>1</peci:Units>
                </peci:Time_Off_Entry>
            </peci:Time_Off_Earnings_and_Deductions>
              </peci:Effective_Change>
        </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

Sample: Output

> 412548 Addtl_TO_Unpaid 3

Currently I am getting

> 412548 Addtl_TO_Unpaid 1
>   412548 Addtl_TO_Unpaid 1
>   412548 Addtl_TO_Unpaid 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: Please share the XSLT code that you have tried so far.